# Dropdown menu behind Flash Object

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a html/css based menu and I'm trying to put a flash video in the banner right under it, but when I hover the dropdown section of the menu it ends up behind it.

Is this a z-index problem or do I need to set certain properties on the flash video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a parameter to the Object tag and a property to the embed tag called wmode and set it to transparent like so:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="798" height="190">
<param name="movie" value="flash/home2.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<PARAM NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
<embed src="flash/home2.swf" quality="high" wmode=transparent pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="798" height="190"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Unless you have parts of the page that you want to see through transparent parts of the Flash movie, use wmode="opaque". Transparent mode uses a lot more CPU power.